# vector joining two points in 3d significance

Tags: vector-spaces, coordinate-systems

Suppose there are two points in Three dimensional system.Then we can represent the two coordinates by their Position vector and joining them will represent another vector .
What would the resulting vector represent....Any coordinate of a point(but isn't every point in 3D represented by position vector) or it serves as the direction for any line line passing through those two points.Can somebody pls explain this to me.

Comment: $P_1 - P_2$ represents the position of $P_2$ relative to $P_1$. This could mean relative position, relative velocity etc depending on context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if you have two points $p_1$ and $p_2$ whose position vectors are $\mathbf{r}_1$ and $\mathbf{r_2}$ rspectively, then the vector connecting the two of them from $p_2$ to $p_1$ is just the difference $\mathbf{r}_1 - \mathbf{r_2}$. I'm not sure I understand your question, but you have to understand that there is a difference between a point in a 3d space and the position vector from the $origin$ to the point. The vector represents all possible points from the origin to the desired point, so the difference $\mathbf{r}_1 - \mathbf{r_2}$ is really the oriented combination of all the points from $p_2$ to $p_1$, but does not start from the origin.

Comment: As much as I know ,any point in 3d can be represented by a position vector from starting from origin and ending at a point.My question for eg vector joining (3,2,1) and (4,5,1) represent. From your answer ,can i conclude it is relative position of a point from the starting point of the vector?

Comment: Yes, you can think of it in this way. Then the distance between these two points is just the modulus of such vector, $|\mathbf{r_1} - \mathbf{r_2}|$.

Answer (score 1):

I like to think about this visually,

Take a note and draw the x-axis and y-axis (after understand 2 dimensions 3 dimensions is the same), then draw 2 vectors from $(0,0)$ to wherever you want, I'll call them $\vec u,\vec v$. Now the vector from the end of $\vec u$ to the end of $\vec v$ is $\vec u-\vec v$. In 3 dimensions it is exactly the same

Comment: But what will that vector represent ...any coordinate or some other thing?

Comment: @HydrousCaperilla the vector of the joint vectors will represent the substraction of those vectors. I can't tell you more because IDK about more, maybe it has more meaning but I never heard about more. I can tell you about usage of that vector and why the fact the it is the substraction of original vectors is a powerful tool if you want